# Different behavior when create ECS cluster using CloudFormation and AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

When create using **CloudFormation**, there is no `Scale ECS Instances` button, to scale the instance you need to find the **Auto Scaling Group** to scale the instance which is not I want.

[image]

When create using **AWS Console**, there is a `Scale ECS Instances` button.

[image]

I want to have the button when create using CloudFormation.

Anything I have missed or did wrong?

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
  "Description":"Create ECS Cluster, ECS Task Definitions, Lambdas, CloudWatchs for different country and environment.",
  "Parameters":{
    "CountryName":{
      "Type":"String",
      "Description":"Auto inclusion launch country name.",
      "AllowedValues":[
        "my",
        "sg"
      ]
    },
    "EnvironmentName":{
      "Type":"String",
      "Description":"An environment name that will be suffixed to resource names.",
      "AllowedValues":[
        "dev",
        "stage",
        "live"
      ]
    },
    "KeyName":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "Description":"Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the ECS instance."
    },
    "VpcId":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description":"Select a VPC to deploy the ECS instance."
    },
    "SubnetId":{
      "Type":"List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description":"Select at least two subnets in your selected VPC to deploy the ECS instance."
    },
    "InstanceType":{
      "Description":"ECS instance type",
      "Type":"String",
      "Default":"t2.micro",
      "AllowedValues":[
        "t2.micro",
        "t2.small",
        "t2.medium",
        "t2.large",
        "m3.medium",
        "m3.large",
        "m3.xlarge",
        "m3.2xlarge",
        "m4.large",
        "m4.xlarge",
        "m4.2xlarge",
        "m4.4xlarge",
        "m4.10xlarge",
        "c4.large",
        "c4.xlarge",
        "c4.2xlarge",
        "c4.4xlarge",
        "c4.8xlarge",
        "c3.large",
        "c3.xlarge",
        "c3.2xlarge",
        "c3.4xlarge",
        "c3.8xlarge",
        "r3.large",
        "r3.xlarge",
        "r3.2xlarge",
        "r3.4xlarge",
        "r3.8xlarge",
        "i2.xlarge",
        "i2.2xlarge",
        "i2.4xlarge",
        "i2.8xlarge"
      ],
      "ConstraintDescription":"Please choose a valid instance type."
    }
  },
  "Mappings":{
    "AWSRegionToAMI":{
      "us-east-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-a7a242da"
      },
      "us-east-2":{
        "AMIID":"ami-b86a5ddd"
      },
      "us-west-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-9ad4dcfa"
      },
      "us-west-2":{
        "AMIID":"ami-92e06fea"
      },
      "eu-west-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-0693ed7f"
      },
      "eu-west-2":{
        "AMIID":"ami-f4e20693"
      },
      "eu-west-3":{
        "AMIID":"ami-698b3d14"
      },
      "eu-central-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-0799fa68"
      },
      "ap-northeast-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-68ef940e"
      },
      "ap-northeast-2":{
        "AMIID":"ami-a5dd70cb"
      },
      "ap-southeast-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-0a622c76"
      },
      "ap-southeast-2":{
        "AMIID":"ami-ee884f8c"
      },
      "ca-central-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-5ac94e3e"
      },
      "ap-south-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-2e461a41"
      },
      "sa-east-1":{
        "AMIID":"ami-d44008b8"
      }
    }
  },
  "Resources":{
    "ECSCluster":{
      "Type":"AWS::ECS::Cluster",
      "Properties":{
        "ClusterName":{
          "Fn::Join":[
            "-",
            [
              {
                "Ref":"AWS::StackName"
              },
              {
                "Ref":"EnvironmentName"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "ECSSecurityGroup":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties":{
        "GroupDescription":"Auto Inclusion Security Group",
        "VpcId":{
          "Ref":"VpcId"
        }
      }
    },
    "ECSSecurityGroupSSHinbound":{
      "Type":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties":{
        "GroupId":{
          "Ref":"ECSSecurityGroup"
        },
        "IpProtocol":"tcp",
        "FromPort":"22",
        "ToPort":"22",
        "CidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"
      }
    },
    "ECSAutoScalingGroup":{
      "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties":{
        "VPCZoneIdentifier":{
          "Ref":"SubnetId"
        },
        "LaunchConfigurationName":{
          "Ref":"ECSLaunchConfiguration"
        },
        "MinSize":"0",
        "MaxSize":"1",
        "DesiredCapacity":"1"
      }
    },
    "ECSLaunchConfiguration":{
      "Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties":{
        "ImageId":{
          "Fn::FindInMap":[
            "AWSRegionToAMI",
            {
              "Ref":"AWS::Region"
            },
            "AMIID"
          ]
        },
        "InstanceType":{
          "Ref":"InstanceType"
        },
        "IamInstanceProfile":{
          "Ref":"EC2InstanceProfile"
        },
        "KeyName":{
          "Ref":"KeyName"
        },
        "SecurityGroups":[
          {
            "Ref":"ECSSecurityGroup"
          }
        ],
        "UserData":{
          "Fn::Base64":{
            "Fn::Join":[
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash\n",
                "echo ECS_CLUSTER=",
                {
                  "Ref":"ECSCluster"
                },
                " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "EC2Role":{
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties":{
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
          "Statement":[
            {
              "Effect":"Allow",
              "Principal":{
                "Service":[
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action":[
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path":"/",
        "ManagedPolicyArns":[
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
        ],
        "Policies":[
          {
            "PolicyName":"auto-inclusion",
            "PolicyDocument":{
              "Version":"2012-10-17",
              "Statement":[
                {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[
                    "s3:GetObject",
                    "s3:ListBucket",
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:DeleteObject"
                  ],
                  "Resource":[
                    "*"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Effect":"Allow",
                  "Action":[
                    "dynamodb:*"
                  ],
                  "Resource":[
                    {
                      "Fn::Join":[
                        "",
                        [
                          "arn:aws:dynamodb:",
                          {
                            "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                          },
                          ":",
                          {
                            "Ref":"AWS::AccountId"
                          },
                          ":table/ai-process-tracking-",
                          {
                            "Ref":"EnvironmentName"
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "EC2InstanceProfile":{
      "Type":"AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "Properties":{
        "Path":"/",
        "Roles":[
          {
            "Ref":"EC2Role"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs":{
    "ecscluster":{
      "Value":{
        "Ref":"ECSCluster"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "[...] which is not I want." can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: As a general rule, the correct way to scale resources created by CloudFormation is to modify your CloudFormation template and then do a update. Otherwise your resources don't match the template and you have potentially lost your ability to automate through CloudFormation.

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard I want to have the `Scale ECS Instances` button when create using CloudFormation.

Comment: @jarmod I understand that is the best practice, but I curious why there is such different

Comment: I must then reiterate on what @jarmod said. You really should embrace  IaC and forget about blue buttons. You could even take the time to set up dynamic autoscaling based on metrics from ECS. So this wouldn't even be hurdle for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I found this in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html).

> If your cluster was created with the [console first-run experience](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-ecs-console-first-run-troubleshoot-docker-errors/) after November 24th, 2015, then the Auto Scaling group associated with
>   the AWS CloudFormation stack created for your cluster can be scaled up
>   or down to add or remove container instances. You can perform this
>   scaling operation from within the Amazon ECS console.
>
> **If your cluster was not created with the console first-run experience after November 24th, 2015, then you cannot scale your
>   cluster from the Amazon ECS** console. However, you can still modify
>   existing Auto Scaling groups associated with your cluster in the Auto
>   Scaling console.

---

Ref: [Scaling Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html)

> If a Scale ECS Instances button appears, then you can scale your
>   cluster in the next step. If not, you must manually adjust your Auto
>   Scaling group to scale up or down your instances, or you can manually
>   launch or terminate your container instances in the Amazon EC2
>   console.

Comment: I updated the answer: If your cluster was not created with the console first-run experience after November 24th, 2015, then you cannot scale your cluster from the Amazon ECS console. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: If your cluster was not created with the console first-run experience after November 24th, 2015, then you cannot scale your cluster from the Amazon ECS console.

ORIGINAL:

this is just a step by step explanation how to get the button, you'll need to reflect this in your CloudFormation template.

- Create an empty ECS cluster, like **my-test-cluster**
- Go to CloudFormation, and create stack named **EC2ContainerService-my-test-cluster** using your template
- Template might need to have the following

```
Outputs:
  TemplateVersion:
    Value: '2.0.0'
  UsedByECSCreateCluster:
    Value: 'true'
```

Comment: If your cluster was not created with the console first-run experience after November 24th, 2015, then you cannot scale your cluster from the Amazon ECS console.